# FTP to IIS 6 Server from IIS 7 Server ASP.NET MVC

Tags: iis-7, iis-6

I have very little experience with IIS 7 and FTP on IIS 7. Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Our application is being developed using ASP.NET, C#.NET, MVC, Oracle, Visual Studio 2008. I am trying to upload files from the local machine to the Server using FTP. We have 4 servers and 3 of them are running Windows Server 2003(IIS 6) and another one is running Windows Server 2008 (IIS 7). 

I am able to upload files (.jpg, .pdf, .txt etc..) using FTP (webrequest) to all the servers. I am able to copy files (FTP) from one Windows Server 2003 IIS6 to another Windows Server 2003 IIS6 machine without any problem. 
  But I am unable to copy files (using FTP) from Windows Server 2008 with IIS7 to Windows Server 2003 IIS6 ..

 I am using IIS 6 FTP on IIS 7. 
I have also tried using FTP 7.5 but it is not very helpful. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Voted to migrate to ServerFault, as it's very likely this is a server configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like FTP issue. I suspect a difference in firewall settings. 
To troubleshoot, I would recommend to install free FTP client app, such as FileZilla and manually test the uploads and downloads. Filezilla would show you the request/response details that may help to understand the root cause of your problem.
You should also check the FTP server log files.

Comment: Thanks Jaro. I will check it out.